# Design in Windows7 and IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I have designed a webpage that can display properly in Windows XP (IE8) . But, when I test this page in Windows7(IE8) , this page cannot display properly. I would like to know It is concerned with Windows7 Theme or not. What could I do to fit my design. Please help me.

With regards,

Comment: Make sure your html is valid: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: thank you so much, I must check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences regarding css. When I used two divs, the first floated left and the second overflow:hidden; width:auto; IE8 on windows 7 rendered it correctly whereas IE8 on xp sp2 rendered the second div giving it incorrect width. Wierd!

And also there are at least 6 versions of MSIE 8 and there are likely differences in layout due to bug fixes in the latter releases. A list of versions is available on [Microsoft's support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393)

MSIE8 on Windows XP is version 8.00.6001.18702 and on Windows 7 is version 8.00.7600.16385.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now, My design floated to left. If so , what could I do to fit it.